# How to access a Qtitan view's scrollbars?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm looking to respond to scroll events from within a Qtitan view. From a normal QT widget, I would connect(...) a signal from the widget's scrollbars. In Qtitan, the underlying scrollbars don't seem to be visible.

My setup is a QMainWindow which uses a QWidget as it's CentralWidget, where that QWidget holds a Qtitan::Grid in it's layout.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is nothing appropriate in the API, try to find scrollbar objects manually:

```
widget->findChildren<QScrollBar*>()
```

Scrollbars can be distinguished using `QScrollBar::orientation()`.